# How can I create multiple barcodes at the same time using Python and pdf417

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pdf417

I'm looking to write a few hundred barcodes for work. I want it to be done at the same time as to not manually run a script for each barcode. The script I currently have only writes one barcode when I need 400.

```
from pdf417 import encode, render_image, render_svg

r1 = 0
r2 = 401

def createlist(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2)]

results = ((createlist(r1, r2)))

results = [str(i) for i in results]

#print(results)


for item in results:
    #print(str(item))
    codes = encode(str(item), columns=3, security_level=2)
    image = render_image(codes, scale=5, ratio=2, padding=5, fg_color="Indigo", bg_color="#ddd")  # Pillow Image object
    image.save('barcode.jpg')
```

This script returns only one barcode file when I need 400 of them returned. This is python 3.7 and the latest release of Pdf417. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is writing 400 barcodes (actually, 401 barcodes), but it does so by writing them all to the same filename, replacing the previous barcode file each time it writes a new one.

To generate separate files, you simply need to vary the filename. For example:

```
from pdf417 import encode, render_image, render_svg

r1 = 0
r2 = 401

def createlist(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2)]

results = ((createlist(r1, r2)))

results = [str(i) for i in results]

#print(results)


for item in results:
    #print(str(item))
    codes = encode(str(item), columns=3, security_level=2)
    image = render_image(codes, scale=5, ratio=2, padding=5, fg_color="Indigo", bg_color="#ddd")  # Pillow Image object
    image.save(f'barcode{item}.jpg')
```

This generates `barcode0.jpg` through `barcode400.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I believe you weren't enumerating your `barcode.jpg` and were writing to the same file multiple times. You'll want to do to 400 as well to create only 400 barcodes.

```
from pdf417 import encode, render_image, render_svg

r1 = 0
r2 = 400

def createlist(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2)]

results = ((createlist(r1, r2)))

results = [str(i) for i in results]

#print(results)


for item in results:
    #print(str(item))
    codes = encode(str(item), columns=3, security_level=2)
    image = render_image(codes, scale=5, ratio=2, padding=5, fg_color="Indigo", bg_color="#ddd")  # Pillow Image object
    image.save('barcode{0}.jpg'.format(item))
```